# Android client-server application works only on the same network

Tags: android, client-server

I'm trying to create a client-server application using Android. I succeeded in making it work on the same network. But it doesn't work otherwise.

The client's socket doesn't connect to the server's.

So I thought it may be because the port is closed. is it possible that that is the cause? And if so how can I open the port in my Android application?

Comment: You should write a bit about the server and how it is configured. Your problem is impossible to solve from this description alone.

Comment: My question concludes to this: how to open ports in android application

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question, most notably added your last comment to the question. You could improve your question by explaining if it is the server that is an Android device, the client, or both. And perhaps explain what you mean by "the same network" - the same LAN? How are the client and server connecting, via a wired connection or wireless? Edit this information into your question, and we may be able to help you better. Good luck!